# Redirect to page with loading animation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, animation

I already know [this solution.](http://blog.ysatech.com/post/2010/02/06/ASPNET-redirect-a-web-page-with-AJAX-loading-indicator-image.aspx) (transfer the slow loading page to a loading-interim-page which shows the animation and then redirects to the actual page)

But I would really like to solve this without a redirecting page.
Any clue how ?
The redirect will be triggered from codebehind...

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.documentElement) {
        document.documentElement.className = 'loading';
    }
</script>
...
</head>
```

Stick that in your `<head>` tag, then add some CSS to hide everything on the page except for your loading animation. For example:

```
.loading > body > * {
    display:none;
}
.loading body {
    background:#fff url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

Then add some JavaScript to clear the `html` tag's class name when the page has finished loading:

```
// Using jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    $(document.documentElement).removeClass('loading');
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but going into the right direction. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @dll32 You might be able to add some nice transitions from the *loading* animation to the full page with some calls to fadeIn() / fadeOut()

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with jQuery.
http://pure-essence.net/2010/01/29/jqueryui-dialog-as-loading-screen-replace-blockui/

And one more simple
http://javascript.internet.com/css/pre-loading-message.html

Comment: As this merely is a matter of 'cosmetics', I don't intend to work on a proper solution, but am looking for an "out of the box solution". 

I'd be suprised if I there were no solutions available...but then again, I couldn't find what I was looking for on a google...

Answer (score 0):

You may see Example This by following this link
http://onlineshoping.somee.com/
This is very easy way to display loading animation, while page is loading each time.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (this.IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<div id=\"loading\" style=\" text-align:center; top:100px;\"><p> Please Wait...</p><br/><img src=\"../Your Animation .gif file path\" \"width:400px\"></div>");
            Response.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);//You may increase Or decrees Thread Sleep time 
            Response.Write("<script>document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';</script>");
        }
}
```

You may download ajax custom animation .gif file from this web site http://ajaxload.info/

I hope it will solve your problem.